# For Loop Range with Smaller Number on Right

Tags: algorithms, syntax, pseudocode

Simple question from an algorithm noob...

If $i=1$ then the inner loop will include what I believe to be an invalid range. Is this acceptable pseudocode?

```
For i=1 to n
  For k=1 to i-1
    ...
```

Comment: "If i=1 then the highlighted text will include what I believe to be an invalid range". Why is it an invalid range? Is empty set a valid set? Is empty range a valid range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is acceptable.

The loop says “do something for each integer $k$ in some range”. If there is no integer in that range, the loop just won’t do anything.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me.